# How does the <button> element know to execute a form action?

Tags: php, html, forms

Forgive me if I use incorrect terminology, or if this seems like a silly question. I'd appreciate any help.

I have a simple webpage, with php code that is suppose to execute when you press a button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

<?Php
echo "<form method=post action='script.php'>";
?>

<div>
<button>Click me</button>
</div>

</body>
```

The 'script.php' looks like this. Just a simple page that prints "Hello" statement.

```
<html>

<body>
<p> Hello </p>
</body>

</html>
```

But how does the <button> element placed after the php script know to do. How are they attached together?

```
action='script.php'
```

I noticed I that I could place a hundred buttons, and they all will execute the form. If fact, any button I place after the php script will behave the same.

```
<button>Button</button>
<button>Button</button>
<button>Button</button>
```

But why? What am I missing?

I tried looking online and on stack overflow but I wasn't even sure what question to ask or what to search for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add closing tag `</form>`

When button is inside `<form>` tag.

```
<button type="submit">Click me</button>
```

While when button is outside `<form>` tag, assign id in form tag

```
<form id="formID">
<button type="submit" form="formID">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the activation behavior of the `button` element itself.

By default, if the `type` attribute is not specified, or if it is set to `submit`, then the default action of the button is to submit the form that it is contained within. When the button is clicked, the browser will send a request to the server with the data from all the form fields, using the method specified in the method attribute of the form element, which is `post` in your PHP.

Check out the official documentation [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-button-element). Cheers!